# What is the name of this 1.25mm pitch 2x5-pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I am experimenting with a VoIP phone from the [NEC DT700 series](https://elinux.org/NEC_DT700-series_VoIP_phone), and it uses a connector like this to access a serial console on a UART:

[image: Close up of connector in question]

I would like to buy a matching plug so that I can easily plug in to the serial console as needed, as the small pins are only <s>0.8mm</s> 1.25mm apart and so very difficult to attach probes to.  However I do not know what to search for!

Does anyone know what this type of connector is called?

EDIT: I originally had this as 0.8mm pin pitch but as pointed out in the answer, it's actually 1.25mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the part number of that connector is [DF13E-10DP-1.25V](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF13E-10DP-1-25V-51/6148486) although the pitch on it is actually 1.25mm.

Here’s a link to the [catalog](https://www.hirose.com/en/product/document?clcode=&productname=&series=DF13&documenttype=Catalog&lang=en&documentid=D31687_en). The mating part number is [DF13-10DS-1.25C](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF13-10DS-1-25C/241805).

Unfortunately I couldn’t find any in stock so it may be hard to find, but you can harvest one from an [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X6JG9R3)

Comment: It certainly looks the part!  On my connector, I measure 5.04mm between the five pins on one side.  But apparently I didn't calculate it properly, because 5.04mm divided by 4 pins gives very close to 1.25mm, so you were right!

Comment: I found a seller on Aliexpress selling [28AWG 300MM DF13 1.25mm Pitch DF13 Series 1.25 mm pitch Connector Wire Harness double head](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002519179265.html) which looks like what I'm after.

Comment: @Malvineous Please note that 1.27mm is the most common pitch and 1.25mm is an oddball one. It's pretty hard to measure with a caliper, though if you get 5.04 the pitch might be 1.00mm which is also a common one.